# Techniques for estimating curves similarity

Tags: signal-processing, similarity

I am attempting to estimate the similarity between three different entities (here expressed as curves).
One of the curves represent a "teacher" (green curve) and the other two are "students".

While researching how to solve this problem, I have come across multiple techniques:

- Procrustes Analysis [Procrustes Analysis with NumPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18925181/procrustes-analysis-with-numpy/18927641#18927641)
- Peak Finding [Peak finding algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929108/peak-finding-algorithm)
- Minkowski Distance (to penalize the outliers heavier)

All three methods have their own advantages and disadvantages, however neither of them seem to help me with the problem demonstrated in the image:

- I "know" that "student 3" (orange curve) is closer to the "teacher", however distance wise "student 5" is measured as closest one
- Peak estimations works well for sharp edges, and it does not perform well here.

[image: Three curves for estimating their similarity]

I do not have a background in signal processing (which is what the problem appears to be requiring), and I would appreciate general suggestions/techniques on how to address these types of problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem isn't necessarily related to signal processing but to curve fitting or optimization in general. When you say that student 3 is "closer", you have to define "closeness".When using pre-defined distance function like you did, you have arbitrarily chosen a distance measure which isn't necessarily suitable to your needs.Estimating from the drawing, I think that by using Euclidean distance you'll get what you want (that student 3 is closer).

Comment: Thanks @Gabe. I am using a generalized euclidian distance - minkowski distance. I am going to run through the results again, but I think it didn't give me what I wanted which I why I started to look at peak analysis (I am glad I do not need signal processing here yet and this problem is solvable with distance measure)

Comment: Yes, indeed - Euclidian distance (or minkowski with p=2) works fine here. I must have been looking at a different instance of the curves at a time.